# VisualCodeのC#においてエラー箇所に波線が出ないのは正しい動作なのか？そしてどうやったら表示できるのか

Tags: c#, vscode

MacOS11.1、Code1.52.1です。一応Unityで使用しています。
CodeでC#を使用していますが、入力しても、ファイルを保存しても、VisualStudioのようにエラー箇所に波線が出ません。
これはおかしいのではないかと思いましたが、ひょっとしたらそれは皆さんも同じかもしれないと思い、

・まずこれは正常な動作なのかどうか教えていただきたく思います。

・そして正常であっても正常でなくても、C#のファイルでエラー箇所を表示できる方法があれば教えてほしいです。

[image: 分かりやすくするため敢えて乱雑になっています]

Comment: 色々な物の版数とか関係しそうですが、この辺が参考になるかも。[Unity Development with VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/other/unity), [VSCode + Unityでインテリセンスが効かない時の対処方法](https://tamilabo.com/2020/11/25/vscode-unity-intellisense/), [VSCode+Unityでインテリセンス(補完/ヒント)が効かないときの対応](https://www.exceedsystem.net/2020/08/25/how-to-enable-intellisense-in-vscode-for-unity/), [今日からUnity + Visual Studio Codeを用いた快適な開発生活(随時更新中)](https://qiita.com/4_mio_11/items/e7b0a5e65c89ac9d6d7f), [【Mac】UnityプロジェクトのインテリセンスがVS Codeで効かない](https://romly.com/blog/unity_mac_vscode_dotnet_fail/)

Comment: ありがとうございます、kunifさんのコメントを元に色々と試したところ表示されるようになりました。やはり出るのが普通ということでしょうか。詳細については自己回答で書きます。

Answer (score 1):

コメント欄での kunif さんのアドバイスにより、以下の手順でエラー表示が動き出しました。

https://romly.com/blog/unity_mac_vscode_dotnet_fail/

・Mac用 Mono の Stable channel をインストール
・VS Code の設定で Use Global Mono を always にする

これがインテリセンスという物だということも知らなかったので、どのように検索すればよいかが分からずにいました、ありがとうございます。